# JSONP autocomplete failing when calling WCF service

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, jsonp

I need to provide a JSONP autocomplete feature for one of our webforms, identical to this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp.

Essentially, I want to dynamically populate a dropdown with values returned from my WCF service that match the search term entered by the user.

The WCF service is successfully hit, and the contents of the textbox are successfully passed in as search parameters.  The webservice returns, but I always fall into the "error:" block in the jQuery.

Here's the retooled jQuery (taken from the AutoComplete sample linked above) which calls my own WCF service:

```
$("#txtModels").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:12345/webapi/models",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                search: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");  //never reach here
                //response($.map(data.models, function (item) {
                //   return {
                //        label: item.model,
                //        value: item.model
                //    }
                //}));
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error");  //always an error
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //log(ui.item ?
        //    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
        //    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    },
    open: function () {
        //$(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function () {
        //$(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
});
```

Here's the WCF service. It does get hit and returns without error.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,  //tried ".Bare" also
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "models?search={search}")]
public string[] GetBoxSerialNums(string search)
{
    string[] models = new string[]{"Ford", "Chevy", "Honda"};
    return models;
}
```

The WCF project was created using the built-in WCF template so my web.config is empty of endpoint configurations, but here it is anyway:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--removed-->
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <!-- 
            Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
                        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
        -->
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="10240000" maxBufferSize="10240000" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <appSettings>
    <!--removed-->
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

I'm quite new to jQuery/JSON, and especially to JSONP, but its pretty obvious the webservice isn't returning data in a format expected by the jQuery call. What do I need to do in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Change you web.config by adding `bindings` inside of `system.serviceModel`:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And add `bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"` to your `<endpoint>` tag.

Then finally change your web method by removing `BodyStyle` and `UriTemplate`:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,  //tried ".Bare" also
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
           //UriTemplate = "models?search={search}"
           )]
public string[] GetBoxSerialNums(string search)
```

Now the response of the WCF service should be something like this:

```
jQuery16409075580490753055_1354078880656(["Ford","Chevy","Honda"]);
```

Which matches the JSONP requirement and should work.

Comment: "And add `bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"` to your <endpoint> tag." Can you clarify? Where in web.config does this go, as I dont currently have any endpoints explicitly defined.  *edit: also, will this affect my other wcf services in the same solution? I obvioulsy don't want to break existing functionality.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure about that as I havent used WCF for JSONP before, I just added a WCF service (.svc) to my existing Testapplication (.net MVC) and messed around with it as I was curious if I get it working (and I did, like described). I don't know why you dont have endpoint configurations?

Comment: The project was created from a template (File -> New -> Project -> Online Templates -> WCF Rest Service Template) which gives you a bare web.config. I ended up scrapping this approach and went with a json/webservice solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, no worries. As long as you are on the same server you should use json, thats right. But I thought you are using jsonp because you are not on the same server?

Comment: Correct, initially the solution was not going to run on the same server so I was focusing on jsonp. In the end I was able to host on the same server so I went with the simpler json approach. WCF and all its configuration is messy so I'm glad to get away from it.